# Functions and convergence in law

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in some metric space $M$. Let $\{\phi_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions from $M$ to another metric space $\tilde M$. Suppose that $\phi_n(X)$ converges in law to a random variable $Y$. Must it be the case that the pairs $(X, \phi_n(X))$ converge in law to a pair $(X, \phi(X))$, where $\phi$ is a measurable function such that $\phi(X)$ has the same law as $Y$?

Comment: When $M$ and $\widetilde M$ are separable, did you try to use Skorohod representation?

Comment: Yes, I tried this. It reduces us to the case of showing that if $(X_n)$ all have the same law, $X_n\rightarrow X$, $\phi_n(X_n) \rightarrow Y$ a.s., then $Y$ is a.s. a function of $X$. However, I don't see a way to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the answer is no. Follows a counter-example with Bernoulli random variables (if you prefer continuous variables, you can construct something similar with the central limit theorem, see the end of my answer).

Let $X$ be a sequence of independent random variables with uniform distribution on the discrete space $\Bbb Z_2$ and let $\phi_n(x) = x_1 + \dots + x_n$. There is trivially convergence in law for $\phi_n(X)$ because for every $n$, the sum $X_1+\dots+X_n$ has uniform distribution on $\Bbb Z_2$.

Suppose that there is some random variable $Y$ such that $(X,\phi_n(X))$ converges in law to $(X,Y)$.

Consider an arbitrary function $f \colon \Bbb Z_2 \to \Bbb R$ and an arbitrary event $A \in \sigma(X_1,\dots,X_k)$. For every $n \geq k+1$, the random variables $1_A$ and $\phi_n(X)$ are independent. Taking the identity
$$
\Pr(A)\cdot E[f(\phi_n(X))] = E[1_A\cdot f(\phi_n(X))]
$$
to the limit, we see that $\Pr(A)\cdot E[f(Y)] = E[1_A\cdot f(Y)]$.

As a consequence, the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. If $Y$ was to be some $\phi(X)$, then it would be constant. This is absurd.

---

Let $X$ be a sequence of i.i.d. real random variables with $E(X_1)=0$ and $E(X_1^2)=1$. The central limit theorem asserts that
$$
\phi_n(X) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{law} Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$

This would require a proper proof but I think that the following is true (because $1/\sqrt{n}$ "kills" $X_1,\dots,X_k$ for finite $k$):

*If $(X,\phi_n(X))$ converges in law to $(X,Y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.*

Another consequence of this is that in the CLT, there is never almost sure convergence (or convergence in probability) for the sequence $\phi_n(X)$. Notice that this is not in contradiction with the *Almost Sure CLT*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems though that the function $\phi_n(X)$ is not independent of $\sigma(X_1 , ... , X_k)$ for $n >k$. Indeed, if we switch the value of one of the $X_j$'s for $j\leq k$, then $\phi_n(X)$ changes from 0 to 1 or vice versa.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think this contradicts the definition of independence in Probability Theory.

Comment: @user15464: Do you agree?

Comment: I still do not agree with your first construction. I think your second construction is somewhat better though. What topology are you using for X?

Comment: Have you checked the definition of independence? Or is there something else you don't agree with? The topology used is the product topology (note that it is metrizable).

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. My mistake. The first example is fine, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A more elementary counterexample: Let $X$ have uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ and define $\phi_n(x):=x$ when $n$ is odd, and $\phi_n(x):=1-x$ when $n$ is even. It's clear that every $\phi_n(X)$ has the same distribution (namely, that of $X$), hence we have convergence in law. However, the pair $(X,\phi_n(X))$ doesn't converge in law to anything, since its distribution keeps flipping back and forth.