# A sequence of random variables that does not converge in probability.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I was doing a problem about the converge of the sum of random variables which has two parts:

> Let $X_1, X_2 ,\dots$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with $E X_i = 0$, $ 0 <\operatorname{Var}(X_i) < \infty $, and let $S_n = X_1 + \dots+ X_n$.
>
> (a) Use the central limit theorem and Kolmogorov's zero-one law to conclude that $ \limsup S_n / \sqrt{n} = \infty$ almost surely.
>
> (b) Use an argument by contradiction to show that $S_n / \sqrt{n}$ does not converge in probability. Hint: Consider $n = m!  $.

---

I did part (a) but I'm not sure about my proof and people are welcome to go through it:

(a) Let $\operatorname{Var} (X_i) = \sigma ^2$, then by central limit theorem $\frac{S_n} {\sigma \sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow \chi$ where $\chi$ has the standard normal distribution. Therefore for any $x > 0$, $P( \limsup \frac{S_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} > x ) \ge P (\chi > x ) > 0$, thus $P ( \limsup \frac{S_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} > x) = 1$ for any $x>0$ by Kolmogorov's zero-one law. By monotonicity this implies $ P ( \limsup \frac {S_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty) =1 $, which is $\limsup \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty$ a.s.

But I stuck with part (b), my approach is the following:

(b) Suppose $ \frac{ S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in probability, then the subsequence $\frac{S_{m!}}{\sqrt{m!}}$ has a further subsequence that converges almost surely.

But it doesn't seem to work out well and I don't think I can go on with it. How to prove part (b)? Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: For part (b): if there was convergence in probability, the limit would be independent of the $X_i$'s (adapt the arguments of [this related answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/579376/51594)) and at the time $\sigma(X_i ; i \geq 1)$-measurable. So it should be constant, which is absurd (by the CLT).

Comment: @user112564, why is $P(\chi > x)>0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part looks ok, but I would apply central limit theorem, not the law of large number. The lower bound of the probability of the $\limsup$ has to be justified (portmanteau theorem).

For part b), we can use the following idea: in the case $S_n/\sqrt n\to \chi$ in probability, we would have 
$$Y_n:=\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}-\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\to 0 \mbox{ in probability}.$$
But $Y_n=\frac{S_{2n}-S_n}{\sqrt{2n}}+\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\left(\frac 1{\sqrt 2}-1\right)=:Y'_n+Y''_n$. Since $S_{2n}-S_n$ is independent of $S_n$, we can compute the limit in distribution of each of the two terms which compose $Y_n$. Notice that $Y'_n$ has the same distribution as $S_n/\sqrt{2n}$ which converges in distribution to a centered normal random variable of variance $\sigma^2/2$, while $Y''_n$ converges in distribution to a centered normal random variable of variance $\sigma^2(1-\sqrt 2)^2/2$. Therefore, it can be shown that $Y_n$ converges to a non-degenerated Gaussian random variable.

Comment: @kayak I have added more details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate it much. But I now know $Y_{n}\rightarrow 0$ in probability and $Y_{n}\rightarrow Y$ in distribution where $Y$ is a non-degenerated Gaussian random variable. But how can we get a contradiction here?

Comment: Convergence in probability to $0$ implies convergence in distribution to $0$, and the limit in distribution is unique.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Oh.. Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Can we conclude that sum of random variables each weakly converges to normal random variable converges weakly to normal random variable? I don't see how the last line can be deduced from those informations.

Comment: @Bergsom Here the key point is independence. You can compute the limit of the characteristic function of $Y_n$ by says that it is the limit of the product of the characteristic functions of $Y'_n$ and $Y''_n$ respectively.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo The property you are using at the end is that if $Y_n' \to Y$ weakly, $Y_n'' \to Y''$weakly, $Y_n', Y_n''$  are independent for each $n$, and $Y',Y''$ are also independent, then $Y_n'+Y_n'' \to Y'+Y''$ weakly. But notice that we need to check the independence of the limits $Y, Y'' $ as well, so how do we check that? We only know about the independence of every $Y_n',Y_n''$

Comment: @some_math_guy Actually, we use that $$\mathbb{E}\left(e^{it(Y'_n+Y''_n)}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(e^{itY'_n }\right)\mathbb{E}\left(e^{it Y''_n}\right) \to  e^{-t^2(\frac{\sigma^2}2 +\sigma^2(1-\sqrt 2)^2/2)/2}$$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Don't you agree that we need the independence of Y', Y'' is one of the assumptions of the theorem that I mentioned? This is the proof I have from the property I mentioned (whose statement is on jacob Proter exercise 19.3 and whose proof I saw in a lecture so I know it is true):

Comment: We have $\Phi_{Y_n'+Y_n''}=\Phi_{Y_n'}\Phi_{Y_n''}\to \Phi_{Y'}\Phi_{Y''} $ (where first we used the independence of $Y_n', Y_n''$  and then Paul's Lévy's theorem for the limit. Now to write $\Phi_{Y'}\Phi_{Y''} =\Phi_{Y'+Y''} $ we need the independence of  $Y', Y''$.  So we have that $\Phi_{Y_n'+Y_n''}\to \Phi_{Y'+Y''}$Then we can conclude by Paul Levy again that this implies $Y_n'+Y_n'' \to Y'+Y''$ weakly. So I don't see how you managed to conclude without making sure that that hypothesis is also respected

Comment: You do not need to identify the limit as the sum of two independent random variables; we just see that the characteristic function converges pointwise to that of a Gaussian distribution and this is enough. If you really want to make appear independent $Y'$ and $Y''$, you can see that the obtain characteristic function is that of $Y'+Y''$ where $Y'$ and $Y''$ have a centered normal distribution with respective variances $\sigma^2/2$ and $\sigma^2(1-\sqrt 2)^2/2$.