# My proof that $S_n/\sqrt n$ does not converge in probability

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

I'm given a sequence $(X_n)$ of  i.i.d. random variables with mean $0$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. Let $S_n=X_1 + ... + X_n$. I have to show that $S_n/\sqrt n$ does not converge in probability. Here's what I did.

Since $S_n/\sqrt n$ converges in distribution to a normal random variable $Z$ with mean zero, if $S_n/\sqrt n$ converges in probability at all it must be to $Z$. But

$$P(|\frac {S_n} {\sqrt n} - Z| > \epsilon) \geq P(|\frac {S_n} {\sqrt n}|<\epsilon, |Z|>2\epsilon)$$

Now I get to the main point I'm not sure of. Can I say that the random variables $S_n\sqrt n$ (for any $n$) and $Z$ are independant? It seems like they might be, since in some sense we can't tell what the limit of a sequence will be from any initial segment of it.

If so, then I can continue (this all seems correct to me)

$$\begin{align}
&P(|\frac {S_n} {\sqrt n}|<\epsilon, |Z|>2\epsilon) \\
=&P(|\frac {S_n} {\sqrt n}|<\epsilon)P(|Z|>2\epsilon) \\
\geq&(1 - \frac {\sigma^2} {n\epsilon^2})P(|Z|>2\epsilon) \to P(|Z|>2\epsilon) > 0
\end{align}$$

Comment: I would suppose that $S_n$ converges in probability for some $X_j$ (e.g., when they are normal distributed). It is only not true that it converges _for all_ $X_j$. So it feels like there is something wrong with your proof.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A sequence of random variables that does not converge in probability.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595368/a-sequence-of-random-variables-that-does-not-converge-in-probability)

Comment: @Winther I don't think that really answers the question - my question is specifically about whether the approach I used is valid or can be modified to be valid.

Comment: OK, I removed the vote! I'll keep the link above as it might be useful for others.

Comment: If (in a different question) $Y_n$ converges in probability to a non-constant $V$, and $W$ has the same distribution as $V$ but is not almost surely identical, then $Y_n$ might be said to converge in distribution to $V$ and to $W$ but cannot be said to converge in probability to $W$. So your assertion that *"if $S_n/\sqrt n$ converges in probability at all it must be to $Z$"* looks difficult to justify

Answer (score 1):

One can easily construct an entity to which we can say that "$S_n/\sqrt n$ converges in probability".

Take for example $W_n = -X_1+X_2+X_3+...+X_n$

Then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P\left(\left|\frac {S_n}{\sqrt n} - \frac {W_n}{\sqrt n}\right|> \epsilon\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P\left(\left|\frac {2X_1}{\sqrt n} \right|> \epsilon\right) = 0$$

and the criterion for convergence in probability is satisfied.

So I suspect that "$S_n/\sqrt n$ does not converge in probability" must have a more specific and narrow sense in the OP's case.

---

On another front, the established phrase *"$S_n/\sqrt n$ converges in distribution to a random variable Z*" sometimes makes us forget that the phenomenon described by "convergence in distribution" is that the sequence of distribution functions $F_n$ of $S_n/\sqrt n$ converges to a certain distribution function $F$. There is really no $Z$ "at the end of the journey" waiting to "become one" with $S_n/\sqrt n$ .  $Z$ is a random variable, a separate entity from the distribution that characterizes it (which characterizes also an infinite number of other such $Z$'s). If there is no random variable, the question "is $S_n/\sqrt n$ independent of $Z$?" cannot even be posed.

Comment: In response to your last paragraph: Yes, I think for this reason this proof (were it valid) would necessarily have to be posed as a proof by contradiction (unlike many proofs by contradiction which can be rephrased as direct proofs of contrapositives). You have to assume the sequence converges in probability to $Z$ in order to even be able to say what $Z$ is.

Comment: I don't understand your construction though. To what are you claiming your $S_n/\sqrt n$ converges in probability?

Answer (score 0):

Let see if this works.

Set $\sigma^2=1$ (if sigma is 0 the statment is true) and assume $V_n=S_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges in probability to a r.v. Z.
By the CLT, Z has standard normal distribution.

Define $W_n=\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}$. These variables converge to Z in probability too.

Finally, take $T_n=\frac{S_{2n}-S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$. 
T converges in distribution to a standard normal, but in probability to $(\sqrt{2}-1) Z$, because $T_n=\sqrt{2}W_n-V_n$, that has not standard normal distribution.

Comment: $S_{2n}$ and $S_n$ are not independent so I do not see why you can say that $T_n=\frac{S_{2n}-S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in probability to $(\sqrt{2}-1) Z$

Comment: @Henry: if $X_n$ converges to X in probability and $Y_n$ converges to Y in probability too, the sum converges in probability to X+Y regerdless of the relation between the variables

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer. I think what you need is the Cauchy criterion for convergence in probability, which says:

The sequence $\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\geq 1}$ converges in probability if and only if
\begin{align}
P\left(\bigg\vert\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{S_m}{\sqrt{m}}\bigg\vert>\epsilon\right)\stackrel{n,m\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0\quad \text{for every }\epsilon>0.
\end{align}

However, notice that
\begin{align}
&P\left(\bigg\vert\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{S_m}{\sqrt{m}}\bigg\vert>\epsilon\right)=P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{S_m}{\sqrt{m}}>\epsilon\right)+P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{S_m}{\sqrt{m}}<-\epsilon\right)\\
&\geq P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}>2\epsilon,\frac{S_m}{\sqrt{m}}\le\epsilon\right)+P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\le-2\epsilon,\frac{S_m}{\sqrt{m}}>-\epsilon\right)\\
&\geq P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}>2\epsilon\right)+P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\le-2\epsilon\right)+P\left(\frac{S_m}{\sqrt{m}}\le\epsilon\right)+P\left(\frac{S_m}{\sqrt{m}}>-\epsilon\right)-2\\
&\stackrel{n,m\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}2\left(Q(2\epsilon)+Q(-\epsilon)-1\right),
\end{align}
where $Q(x)=\int\limits_{x}^{\infty} \mathcal{N}(0,1)\,dx$.

I do not know how to find an $\epsilon>0$ such that the term inside the brackets is strictly positive. I am not quite sure if we can find one at all. As I said, this is just a partial solution that I have worked out.

Please feel free to suggest any more additions, or strengthening of arguments.

Comment: Actually the last expression is negative for every $\epsilon>0$. But more importantly how do you get your last inequality? It seems that your last inequality uses something like “$P(A\cap B)\ge P(A)+P(B).$”

Comment: I have used the inequality $P(A\cap B) \geq P(A) + P(B) - 1$.