# Are these random variables independent?

Tags: probability-theory

Just as in the central limit theorem, we let $X_i$ be iid with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$, $S_n=X_1+\cdots +X_n$ and let $Y$ be the limit in distribution of $S_n/\sigma\sqrt n$. I think that $S_n/\sigma\sqrt n$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent; any good examples?

Comment: What does the central limit theorem tell you about the limit $Y$?

Comment: That $Y$ has the distribution of $N(0,1).$

Comment: This [other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578248/functions-and-convergence-in-law) might be of interest for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent random variables, $X_i \sim N(0,1)$. By the central limit theorem, $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $Y \sim N(0,1)$. Since this is a limit **in distribution**, we can choose any $Y \sim N(0,1)$, e.g. we can take $Y := X_1$. Then, clearly, $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $X_1$ are not independent.

The important point is that the central limit theorem only gives a limit distribution. However, the independence of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ does not only depend on the marginals, but on the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. This means that we cannot expect such a statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain why $S_n/\sqrt n$ and $X_1$ are not independent? $S_n/\sqrt n$ converges in distribution to $X_1$... Sorry I know this should be clear.

Comment: @Aubrey Hint: Calculate $\mathbb{E}(X_1 \cdot \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}})$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_1) \cdot \mathbb{E}(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}})$. Are they equal? What does this tell you about the (in)dependence of both variables?

Comment: OK, thanks! One is zero and the other is not.

Comment: @Aubrey Yes, exactly.